# Cayenne null pointer error when trying to commit changes

Tags: java, orm, apache-cayenne

I'm  running the following code that errors when I try to commit my changes using Cayenne as my ORM. The code is pasted below and errors out on the     context.commitChanges();line. The output messages are pasted below the code. Any help on figuring this out would be appreciated.

```
import org.apache.cayenne.access.DataContext;
import java.util.*;

import com.jared.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataContext context = DataContext.createDataContext();
        Stocks theStock=(Stocks) context.createAndRegisterNewObject(Stocks.class);
theStock.setAsk(3.4);
theStock.setAvgdailyvolume(323849);
theStock    .setBid(5.29);
theStock.setChange(-1.22);
theStock.setDayhigh(9.21);
theStock.setDaylow(2.11);
theStock.setLasttradeprice(5.11);
theStock.setLasttradesize(3827);
theStock.setOpen(6.21);
theStock.setPriorclose(4.21);
theStock.setShortratio(1.1);
theStock.setSymbol("^SP%");
theStock.setVolume(28193);
theStock.setLasttradedate(new Date());
    context.commitChanges();
    System.out.println("Done with the database");
    }
}
```

```
Nov 20, 2008 11:20:37 PM org.apache.cayenne.conf.RuntimeLoadDelegate startedLoading
INFO: started configuration loading.
Nov 20, 2008 11:20:37 PM org.apache.cayenne.conf.RuntimeLoadDelegate shouldLoadDataDomain
INFO: loaded domain: stocks
Nov 20, 2008 11:20:37 PM org.apache.cayenne.conf.RuntimeLoadDelegate loadDataMap
INFO: loaded .
Nov 20, 2008 11:20:37 PM org.apache.cayenne.conf.RuntimeLoadDelegate shouldLoadDataNode
INFO: loading .
Nov 20, 2008 11:20:37 PM org.apache.cayenne.conf.RuntimeLoadDelegate shouldLoadDataNode
INFO: using factory: org.apache.cayenne.conf.DriverDataSourceFactory
Nov 20, 2008 11:20:37 PM org.apache.cayenne.conf.DriverDataSourceFactory load
INFO: loading driver information from 'stocksNode.driver.xml'.
Nov 20, 2008 11:20:37 PM org.apache.cayenne.conf.DriverDataSourceFactory$DriverHandler init
INFO: loading driver org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
Nov 20, 2008 11:20:37 PM org.apache.cayenne.conf.DriverDataSourceFactory$LoginHandler init
INFO: loading user name and password.
Nov 20, 2008 11:20:37 PM org.apache.cayenne.access.QueryLogger logPoolCreated
INFO: Created connection pool: jdbc:hsqldb:file:/hsqldb/data/stocks
    Driver class: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    Min. connections in the pool: 1
    Max. connections in the pool: 1
Nov 20, 2008 11:20:37 PM org.apache.cayenne.conf.RuntimeLoadDelegate shouldLoadDataNode
INFO: loaded datasource.
Nov 20, 2008 11:20:37 PM org.apache.cayenne.conf.RuntimeLoadDelegate initAdapter
INFO: no adapter set, using automatic adapter.
Nov 20, 2008 11:20:37 PM org.apache.cayenne.conf.RuntimeLoadDelegate finishedLoading
INFO: finished configuration loading in 203 ms.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cayenne.CayenneRuntimeException: [v.3.0M4 May 18 2008 16:32:02] Commit Exception
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataContext.flushToParent(DataContext.java:1192)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataContext.commitChanges(DataContext.java:1066)
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainInsertBucket.createPermIds(DataDomainInsertBucket.java:101)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainInsertBucket.appendQueriesInternal(DataDomainInsertBucket.java:76)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainSyncBucket.appendQueries(DataDomainSyncBucket.java:80)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainFlushAction.preprocess(DataDomainFlushAction.java:183)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainFlushAction.flush(DataDomainFlushAction.java:135)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomain.onSyncFlush(DataDomain.java:821)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomain$2.transform(DataDomain.java:788)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomain.runInTransaction(DataDomain.java:847)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomain.onSync(DataDomain.java:785)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataContext.flushToParent(DataContext.java:1164)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 2):

user name, password?

> ClientConnection connection = new
>   HessianConnection("http://localhost:8080/cayenne-service",
>   "cayenne-user",    "secret",
>   null);